# Include Minit plugin in theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I'm trying to include the [Minit](https://github.com/kasparsd/minit) plugin in the `inc` folder of my WordPress theme and calling it in my `functions.php` file:

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/minit-master/minit.php';
```

However, after its added it doesn't work as it does when it is a plugin and I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **Minit for WordPress** is hooked into the `plugins_loaded` action hook (you can see that checking the file `minit.php`).

And the thing is you are requiring the file `minit.php` in your `functions.php`, which is a file loaded after the hook `plugins_loaded` is called. This means that **Minit** is not being initialized the proper way.

So, basically, you have two choices:

1. Put **minit-master** directory inside your **plugins** directory so you can load `minit.php` like it should be loaded, as a WordPress plugin.
2. Or you could keep the way you want by changing the source code of `minit.php` to be loaded within `after_setup_theme` hook:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Minit
Plugin URI: https://github.com/kasparsd/minit
GitHub URI: https://github.com/kasparsd/minit
Description: Combine JS and CSS files and serve them from the uploads folder.
Version: 1.4.1
Author: Kaspars Dambis
Author URI: https://kaspars.net
*/
// Until we add proper autoloading.
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/minit-assets.php';
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/minit-asset-cache.php';
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/minit-js.php';
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/minit-css.php';
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/minit-plugin.php';
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/admin.php';
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/helpers.php';

// Here we changed from `plugins_loaded` to `after_setup_theme`.
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'Minit_Plugin', 'instance' ) );
```

Comment: Ahh, of course! I can't believe I missed that. Was too busy digging around in the other files. Thanks @filipecsweb !